What do the purple Oaken cards do in Frozen Uno?
I found this set of Frozen Uno at an op shop with no rules included. Most of the cards are just a Frozen version of normal Uno cards, but we can't work out what the two purple Oaken cards (in the bottom row) are for. I looked online, but the sets pictured don't match the one we have. Does anyone know what they do?
(Apologies for the upside down +2 card. I didn't realise until posting that it was upside down.)
Edit: I don't think this is the same as the blank purple UNO cards that the other question has suggested. For starters, it's not really blank, and there's nowhere good to write down a value to use it as a replacement. And there's only 2, as opposed to 4 which the question states comes with a regular UNO deck.


This question is similar to: What is this blank purple UNO card?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Thanks, I've edited the question to explain why I don't think the similar question matches my use case.

The purple cards are not mentioned in the UNO Disney Frozen's rules so it could be 2 additional blank cards that could be used as a replacement card or a house rules card, like mentioned in the UNO rules from 2001.

What are these extra cards for?
Blank Card - This is a special card that you may use in one of two ways. If a card from your UNO deck is lost or damaged, you may use the Blank Card as a replacement.
Example: If you find that your deck is missing one of the yellow 7's, you would simply replace it by taking the yellow Blank Card, marking a "7" on it and adding it back into the deck.
If you family has a special UNO rule you prefer to play with, you may write that rule on the Blank Cards and add them straight to the deck.


Those rules are from this version of uno:
https://cf.geekdo-images.com/X3gNxPOXzNYcN8T59heRqQ__imagepage/img/tALQnGhyoDp5__UzHJdsVuKaBG4=/fit-in/900x600/filters:no_upscale():strip_icc()/pic4916135.jpg
which appears to be different from the pictured cards

I don't think they're blank cards, as unlike the rules in the link, the cards are purple which don't match the colour of any other cards, and there's not really a blank space suitable for writing a replacement value.

They appear to reuse the same art as the Disney Frozen Uno cards, but neither I or II have the same colors or the same image for the same card. Searching for the top card, I found Online Store, where they are out of stock. It is not marked as Disney and probably not an official version.

